# Adding up all columns with multiindex on axis 0

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a multiIndexed pandas dataframe called `df` looking like this:

```
     Rh    0.1     0.2     0.3
x  y  z    
0  0  0    0.125   0.126   0.127
      1    0.134   0.135   0.137
   1  0    ...
```

I want to keep the x,y,z multiIndex and sum up all columns. The call `df.sum(axis=1)` does not give the right result. The desired output should look like:

```
     Rh    sum
x  y  z    
0  0  0    0.378
      1    0.406
   1  0    ...
```

Comment: Please post the full, but minimum amount of code and data to reproduce this. With what you've provided, I get the desired results. Perhaps you have a non-unique index. Check it with `print(df.index.is_unique)`

Comment: indeed, non-unique indices. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Works on my end:

```
from io import StringIO
import pandas

datafile = StringIO("""\
x  y  z    A     B     C
0  0  0    0.125   0.126   0.127
0  0  1    0.134   0.135   0.137
""")

df = pandas.read_table(datafile, index_col=['x', 'y', 'z'], sep='\s+')

df.sum(axis=1)

x  y  z
0  0  0    0.378
      1    0.406
dtype: float64
```

Comment: I noticed that I can't name the column with a float. I get the error `TypeError: the label [0.5] is not a proper indexer for this index type (MultiIndex)` while I won't get this error when I create a dataframe myself with multiindex. Is this the result of sum()?

Comment: see my first comment to your question: post the minimum amount of code and data required to reproduce this problem. In general, labeling a column with a float is at least discouraged, if not wholly unsupported due to the lack of precision associated with the datatype.

Comment: I found out what the issue was. The result of `df.sum()` is a Series and not a DataFrame. It is very dificult to put the minimum code here because the dataframe is generated with a lot of lines (read through sampling specific files from a c++ simulation with libraries from that simulation).

Comment: @tvandenbrande you don't need all the data on SO questions, just the minimum amount to reproduce the problem, the results you're getting, and the results you expect. All three of those pieces are critical to a good pandas question